# How to pass filepath with spaces to QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl()?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside6, qt6

[As shown in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) for `QDesktopServices`, I tried using `QtCore.QUrl.ParsingMode.TolerantMode` to have a file path with URL be used as is (i.e. without having the spaces convert to %20s), but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a problem with my implementation?

```py
>>> from PySide6 import QtGui as qtg
>>> from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc
>>> qtg.QGuiApplication()
<PySide6.QtGui.QGuiApplication(0x22434e0) at 0x7fba08dcbd80>
>>> qtg.QDesktopServices.openUrl(qtc.QUrl("url with spaces", qtc.QUrl.ParsingMode.TolerantMode))
True
>>> xdg-open: file 'url%20with%20spaces' does not exist
```

Comment: try `"\"url with spaces\""` or use `QUrl.fromLocalFile`

Comment: @VladimirBershov `QUrl.fromLocalFile` did it, thanks.